# clearing all open previous activities not working in android 5.0

Tags: android, deep-linking

My app has a log in MainActivity. By tapping on  a link a SecondActivity starts and the user can sign up. After the user completes the form an email is sent with a deep link to activate the account. When the user taps that link the MainActivity starts again indicating that the account was activated and that the user can log in. The problem is that in android 4.3 the previous activities get clear, but not in Android 5:

This is part of the code I'm using when the user taps the deep link:

```
Intent toLaunchMainActivityAgain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
toLaunchMainActivityAgain.addFlags(toLaunchMainActivityAgain.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
toLaunchMainActivityAgain.setFlags(toLaunchMainActivityAgain.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
toLaunchMainActivityAgain.setFlags(toLaunchMainActivityAgain.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to launch another activity, call below to make sure Android Task Manager doesn't store the activity you are leaving

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
```

When I want to then go back to another activity from my current one, I simply call

```
finish();
```